# on ipad stop page movement on Image slider swipe

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad

I have an application that uses a slider which works fine on a PC, but on iPad, when I drag the slider, sometimes instead of moving the slider, it moves the whole page. How can I stop that?

Answer (score 2):

Sliders don't work when the dragging action is needed to move the page around. You can prevent this by disabling the ability to zoom in. Use the iOS-specific meta tags for this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content ="width = device-width, user-scalable = no">
```

The documentation for this is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html).

Comment: Thanks :) Had the same issue, the solution helped!